# Get Mat Accordion open and close state values

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to get the value of the open and close states from my mat-accordion dynamically however it is not working. The component is created so that it can be re-used.

Here is my code

*side-panel-accordian.component.html*

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="data.panelOpenState === true" (closed)="data.panelOpenState === false" [expanded]="data.expanded">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ data?.title }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

*side-panel-accordian.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidePanelAccordianData } from './side-panel-accordian.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-panel-accordian',
  templateUrl: './side-panel-accordian.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-panel-accordian.component.scss']
})
export class SidePanelAccordianComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: SidePanelAccordianData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

*side-panel-accordian.model.ts*

```
export class SidePanelAccordianData {
  public title: string = '';
  public panelOpenState: boolean;

  constructor(args) {
    this.title = args.title;
    this.panelOpenState = args.panelOpenState;
    this.expanded = args.expanded;
  }
}
```

*HTML file where I am trying to use the component*

```
<app-side-panel-accordian [data]="{title:'test text', panelOpenState: true}" expanded: panelOpenState>
  <label class="inner-row-header">test text</label>
  <div class="inner-row-data">
    <p>test text</p>
  </div>
</app-side-panel-accordian>
```

*TS file*

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(panelOpenState);
}
```

How can I get the value of panelOpenState in my TS file?